# multiprocessing.Pool is losing state when calling a function on an object with an existing property in pathlib.Path subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm going a little bug-eyed here trying to troubleshoot this. In the process, I've tried to create a self-contained function to reproduce the issue, but for some reason it works as expected in the micro-example, but not in my prod code.

I have a subclass of pathlib.Path:

```
class WalkPath(Path):

    _flavour = type(Path())._flavour
   
    def __init__(self, *args, origin: 'WalkPath'=None, dirs: []=None, files: []=None):

        super().__init__()
        
        if type(args[0]) is str:
            self.origin = origin or self
        else:
            self.origin = origin or args[0].origin

        self._dirs: [WalkPath] = list(map(WalkPath, dirs)) if dirs else None
        self._files: [WalkPath] = list(map(WalkPath, files)) if files else None

        self._lazy_attr = None

    @staticmethod
    def sync(wp: Union[str, Path, 'WalkPath']):
        """Syncronize lazy-loaded attributes"""
        x = wp.lazy_attr
        return wp

    @property
    def lazy_attr(self):
        if self._lazy_attr:
            return self._lazy_attr:
        # long running op
        self._lazy_attr = long_running_op(self)
        return self._lazy_attr

class Find:

    @staticmethod
    def shallow(path: Union[str, Path, 'WalkPath'],
                sort_key=lambda p: str(p).lower(),
                hide_sys_files=True) -> Iterable['WalkPath']:
        origin = WalkPath(path)
        if origin.is_file(): 
            return [origin]
        
        for p in sorted(origin.iterdir(), key=sort_key):
            if hide_sys_files and is_sys_file(p):
                continue
            yield WalkPath(p, origin=origin)
```

Using `multiprocessing.Pool`, I want to execute that long-running process in a pool.

That looks like this:

```
_paths = ['/path1', '/path2']
found = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(Find.shallow(p) for p in _paths))
```

Find.shallow (see above) basically just does a `Path.iterdir` on origin and then maps the results to a `WalkPath` object, setting the origin to the path called. I know this works, because this outputs correctly:

```
for x in found:
    print(x.origin, x.name)
```

Then we dispatch to a pool:

```
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    done = [x for x in pool.map(WalkPath.sync, found) if x.origin]
```

But this fails, starting `'WalkPath' has no attribute 'origin'`.

Here’s my attempt at reproducing it locally, but for some reason it works! I cannot spot the difference.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from itertools import tee, chain

r = None

class P:
    
    def __init__(self, i, static=None):
        # self.static = static if not static is None else i
        self.static = static or i
        # print(static, self.static)
        self.i = i
        
        self._a_thing = None
    
    @property
    def a_thing(self):
        if self._a_thing:
            print('Already have thing', self.i, 'static:', self.static)
            return self._a_thing
        time.sleep(0.05)
        print('Did thing', self.i, 'static:', self.static)
        self._a_thing = True
        return self._a_thing
    
    @staticmethod
    def sync(x):
        x.a_thing
        x.another = 'done'
        return x if x.a_thing else None
    
class Load:
    
    @classmethod
    def go(cls):
        
        global r
        
        if r:
            return r
               
        paths = [iter(P(i, static='0') for i in range(10)),
                 iter(P(i, static='0') for i in range(11, 20)),
                 iter(P(i, static='0') for i in range(21, 30))]
        
        iternums, testnums = tee(chain.from_iterable(paths))
        
        for t in testnums:
            print('Want thing', t.i, 'to have static:', t.static)
            
        with mp.Pool() as pool:
            rex = [x for x in pool.map(P.sync, list(iternums)) if x.another]
         
        r = rex
            
        for done in rex:
            print(done.i, done.static, done.a_thing, done.another)

Load.go()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux of the problem is that your `Path` objects cannot be shared between interpreter processes.

Instead, when using `multiprocessing`, Python serializes (`pickle`s) all arguments and return values to/from subprocesses.

It seems that `pathlib.Path` defines custom pickling/unpickling logic that is incompatible with your `origin` attribute:

```python
import pathlib
import pickle


class WalkPath(pathlib.Path):

    _flavour = type(pathlib.Path())._flavour

    def __init__(self, *args, origin: 'WalkPath'=None, dirs: []=None, files: []=None):

        super().__init__()

        if type(args[0]) is str:
            self.origin = origin or self
        else:
            self.origin = origin or args[0].origin

        self._dirs: [WalkPath] = list(map(WalkPath, dirs)) if dirs else None
        self._files: [WalkPath] = list(map(WalkPath, files)) if files else None

        self._lazy_attr = None


path = WalkPath('/tmp', origin='far away')
print(vars(path))

reloaded = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(path))
print(vars(reloaded))
```

```
$ python3.9 test.py 
{'origin': 'far away', '_dirs': None, '_files': None, '_lazy_attr': None}
{'origin': WalkPath('/tmp'), '_dirs': None, '_files': None, '_lazy_attr': None}
```

Comment: ARGGGG!!! Ok, well at least I wasn't missing something silly. Thanks for the explanation. Now I need to figure out what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here's how I ended up solving this.

What happens here, is that `Path` implements the `__reduce__` function, which is called before `__getstate__` or `__setstate__` would (which are higher level pickling functions).

Here's the `__reduce__` function from `PurePath`, `Path`'s base class:

```
def __reduce__(self):
    # Using the parts tuple helps share interned path parts
    # when pickling related paths.
    return (self.__class__, tuple(self._parts))
```

Oh no! Well, we can see what happens - this is intentionally designed just to pass a tuple of its parts, dropping state altogether and forming a new version of itself.

I didn't want to mess with that, but I also wanted to make sure my state was preserved here. So I created a serializer that takes these properties as a tuple argument (since... `__reduce__` for some ridiculous reason only takes a single tuple as an argument).

I also had to make sure that `origin` was now a `Path` object, not a `WalkPath` object, otherwise I would have ended up with an endless recursion. I added some type coercion and safety to the `__init__`:

```
if origin:
        self.origin = Path(origin)
    elif len(args) > 0:
        try:
            self.origin = Path(args[0].origin) or Path(args[0])
        except:
            self.origin = Path(self)
    
    if not self.origin:
        raise AttributeError(f"Could not infer 'origin' property when initializing 'WalkPath', for path '{args[0]}'")
```

Then I added these two methods to `WalkPath`:

```
# @overrides(__reduce__)
def __reduce__(self):

    # From super()

    # Using the parts tuple helps share internal path parts
    # when pickling related paths.
    
    # return (self.__class__, tuple(self._parts))

    # This override passes its parts to a Path object (which
    # natively pickles), then serializes and applies 
    # its remaining attributes.
    
    args = {**{'_parts': self._parts}, **self.__dict__}
    return (self.__class__._from_kwargs, tuple(args.items()))

@classmethod
def _from_kwargs(cls, *args):
    kwargs = dict(args)
    new = cls(super().__new__(cls, 
                              *kwargs['_parts']),
                              origin=kwargs['origin'])
    new.__dict__ = {**new.__dict__, **kwargs}
    return new
```